# str.replace causes %2520 instead of the wanted %20

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to replace spaces in an input with a literal `%20` so that the URL contains `%20` and not `+`.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.form-horizontal').submit(function(){
        var str = $('#nickname').val();
        var res = str.replace(" ", "%20");
        $('#nickname').val(res );
      });
    });
  </script>
```

but I end up with `init_user=John%2520Doe` instead of `init_user=John%20Doe`.

I don't have other encoding anywhere and this is the only script instance.

Comment: [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is your friend.

Comment: @tcooc Should I just `encodeURIComponent($('#nickname').val());` instead of the `str.replace`?

Comment: Yes, thats the way to go.

Comment: This suggests that you'd get the correct value by doing no replacement at all, since encoding is happening on its own - `%25` is the encoded value of `%`

Comment: If I do nothing I get `John+Doe` which I don't want. I want `John%20Doe`, literally, in the URL.

Comment: Using `encodeURIComponent($('#nickname').val());` I still get the `%2520`!

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` is unlikely to help you here - it will still replace the `' '` with `%20`, which will still be double-encoded in whatever way that's already happening now - most likely the default form encoding (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) which will translate ` ` as `+`.

Comment: Are you talking to a web server that somehow doesn't understand `+` as an encoding for `' '`? Or relying on some other script that doesn't get it?

Comment: @PaulRoub It is a nickname that the user will enter a chat as. `+` is a valid character in a nickname, so the user is `John+Doe`, it does not get converted to a space since `+` is a valid character. The chat only converts `%20` (not `%2520`!) to a space. If I manually write `John%20Doe` in the URL it works fine, it's just the form is a problem ...

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421144/replace-with-20-in-url-generated

Comment: Show the code that modifies the url. There is probably another problem in that code.

Comment: @tcooc I put the code in the question?

Comment: That means your code is submitted by the browser. The browser will automatically replace `" "` with `"%20"`, you don't need code to do it...

Comment: @tcoc Nope, shows as `+` with no code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the built-in `encodeURI(string)` function (usage as `var encodedString = encodeURI(baseString);`).

Or is there any reason why that is not an option for you in this specific case?